# Strange overflow in Google Chrome, How to fix it?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

This happens only when I do a selection in the page and move the mouse to the right. Can you help? please look the attached picture.[image]

Comment: Please post the code/demo mate. It is difficult/impossible to debug with screenshots.

Comment: enter the website www.crishk.com

Comment: this occurs only on Google Chrome

Comment: It is against SO rules to have a question without atleast a minimal example mate. You cannot expect everybody to access a site which they know nothing about.

Comment: always I came here and get this kind of comments about my questions. This very frustrating, How can I put a code that is on the website and is very strong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for us to help you, you should be posting code snippets instead of a link to your website. It's against the rules as @Harry stated to do anything otherwise.

That said, I think the issue is coming from the fact that you're using elastics widths with your site. Keep in mind that when you do this, you need to watch your padding as in some browsers, they expand the widths beyond the max screen size.

I think the issue for you is coming about as you have:

`article.header {
    background-color: #1949CF;
    padding: 3px;
    padding-top: 7px;
}`

coupled with

`.module {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}`

both being called near the beginning of your code:

`<article class="module header">`

Thus, the `padding: 3px;` is extending the `width: 100%;` set by `.module` to essentially overflow your container.

To see this, use the Chrome -> Inspect Element tool by right clicking on your website.  By hovering over your `<article class="module header">` section, you will see that the width being shown is beyond the max width of your browser window.

This may not be the only spot in your code that needs fixed, but this should get to on the right track of how to debug your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the body's width at 100% with overflow: hidden.

```
 body {
 background-size: 100%;
 background-position: center 1%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 font-family: "Arial Narrow", Arial;
 font-stretch: condensed;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 text-align: center;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 }
```